# How to Save a image recieved via HTTP Post into mySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to write an image received via http into my database using PHP. I access the image with

```
$inputImage = file_get_contents('php://input');
```

Echoing the `$inputImage` works fine, so the transport to the server doesn't seam to be a problem.

I now tried to insert the image with

```
$sqlRequest="INSERT INTO Image(time, data) SET (NOW(), '$inputImage')";
mysqli_query($connection, $sqlRequest) or die("Error in Inserting " . mysqli_error($connection));
```

But it doesn't work and i recieve the following error

> Error in Inserting You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SET (NOW(), '����' at line 1

Can someone give me a hint
thanks

edit:
okay changed the sytax problem, got to look for the blob problem

Comment: that isn't how it works. You're instructing MySQL to set a column named `NOW()` as in a "function". RTM http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/insert.html and using improper syntax, plus you've an encoding problem. You're trying to upload as a BLOB but not doing that. You need to escape it.

Comment: okay I got the wrong syntax, changed it to 
$sqlRequest="INSERT INTO Image (data) Values ($inputImage)"; Still the same problem how to solve the encoding problem?

Comment: is your column set a BLOG or LONGBLOB? plus, you need to escape that file's variable; sounds like a solution to me. Give me a minute, I will write something up for you.

Comment: you're welcome. See my answer I posted for you below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the funny characters `����`, this sounds like you're trying to upload a binary file into a column that isn't capable of handling that type.

Sidenote edit: seeing your comment now, you still need to escape that variable.

By "escape", I mean that you need to use [`mysqli_real_escape_string()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php).

If this isn't set, then you will need to ALTER your column to either be a BLOB or LONGBLOB.

More importantly, you need to escape the contents of `$inputImage` because that will be *binary data* and could contain bytes that will cause MYSQL to assume it is shorter than it actually is.

```
$inputImage = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $inputImage);

$sqlRequest="INSERT INTO Image(time, data) VALUES (NOW(), '$inputImage')";
```

And of course as I already stated in comments under your question, you're using the wrong syntax in your query.

Use `VALUES()` and not `SET()`.

Add `or die(mysqli_error($connection))` to `mysqli_query()` also.

Reference:

- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php

Using a prepared statement would also work:

- http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Comment: thank your very much, works perfectly now but to be honest I didn't understand what it means to escape the variable and what the function does

Answer (score 1):

Use `VALUES()` instead of `SET()`. `SET` is meant for updating (using `UPDATE`) whereas `VALUES()` is meant for inserting (using `INSERT`).

See [this](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp) for `INSERT` syntax and [this](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_update.asp) for `UPDATE` syntax.

Comment: INSERT does allow SET http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert.html they're just doing it wrong. (as per your original http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/34679551/1 )

Comment: Added links for reference to syntax explanation

Comment: okay I got the wrong syntax, changed it to 
$sqlRequest="INSERT INTO Image (data) Values ($inputImage)"; Still the same problem

Comment: The error message would be different I assume? Could you post it?

Comment: SET Syntax also works for insert this is not the problem.

Answer (score 0):

you want to make sure no data obstructing your sql string is stored so do this:

```
$inputImage = base64_encode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
```

before storing the data and then

```
$myImage = base64_decode( myGetImageFromDBFunction( $myImageID )  );
```